# Points of a root in a rooted, connected graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm struggling to see why this is true:

> The number of rooted, labeled graphs in which the root is in a component of exactly $k$ points is $k C_k \binom p k G_{p-k}$.

For reference, the $C_k$ is derived from $C_p$, the number of connected, labelled graphs.

I would appreciate it if someone could help justify that assertion. Thanks!

Comment: what is $C_k$ and $G_{p-k}$?

Comment: $G_{p-k}$ - number of labeled graphs of order p-k and $C_k$ - number of connected, labeled graphs of order k.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the label set $[p]=\{1,\ldots,p\}$. There are $\binom{p}k$ ways to choose a subset of $k$ of these $p$ points to form a component, and there are $C_k$ ways to impose a connected graph structure on those $k$ points, so there are $C_k\binom{p}k$ ways to form a component with $k$ vertices. There are then $k$ ways to choose one of its vertices to be the root, so there are $kC_k\binom{p}k$ ways to build a rooted, labelled component. There are then $G_{p-k}$ different ways to impose a graph structure on the remaining $p-k$ vertices. Each of those structures can be combined with any of the connected graph structures and choice of root for our chosen set of $k$ points, so altogether there are $kC_k\binom{p}kG_{p-k}$ graphs of the specified form.